# Create a MysQL Query on one table and also lookup the value of a field in a second table from field values in 1st table

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find the exact thing I'm looking for.

I want to be able to do a normal sort of query on a "TransactionsTable" I have, but then lookup and show the 'machineDescription' from a "MachineTable" as part of my results. However I need to do this lookup twice for the machine that initiated the transaction and the machine that closed the transaction.

Also notice that 'CreatedId' & 'CompletedId' from "TransactionsTable" are the fields I need to use to search for the 'machineDescription' in the "MachineTable", but in this table the field is called 'machineNumber'.

Here is an example of the table data :-

**TransactionsTable**

```
CreatedId |  Value |  CreatedDate | CompletedId |  CompletedDate | Status
---------------------------------------------------------------------
125       |  100   |  2022/01/01  |  127        |  2022/01/01    | COMPLETE
126       |  100   |  2022/01/05  |  NULL       |  NULL          | ACTIVE
127       |  100   |  2022/01/12  |  126        |  2022/01/14    | COMPLETE
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**MachineTable**

```
machineNumber |  machineDescription |  machineStatus 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
125           |  X100-1             |  ONLINE
126           |  X100-2             |  ONLINE
127           |  Z4000              |  OFFLINE  
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I want to do a normal kind of query e.g. :-

SELECT * FROM TransactionsTable WHERE Status = "COMPLETE" AND 'CreatedDate' BETWEEN "2022-01-01" AND "2022-01-31";

But somehow, I want to lookup the 'machineDescription' for both the 'CreatedId' & 'CompletedId' at the same time and have it output for each record returned, so it would look like this :-

```
CreatedId |  CreatedDesc  |  Value | CreatedDate | CompletedId | CompletedDesc | CompletedDate | Status
---------------------------------------------------------------------
125       |  X100-1       |  100   | 2022/01/01  |  127        |  Z4000        | 2022/01/01    | COMPLETE
```

I presume there is a "JOIN" statement involved in this somewhere but I can't seem to make it work.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Join twice, using a table alias for one or both

Comment: Thanks @ysth, I tried two join statements with table alias but couldn't seem to get it working. I'm now thinking sub queries might be a way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: no, no need for subqueries

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join the MachineTable twice, once to look up each description:

```
select t.CreatedId, m1.machineDescription as CreatedDesc, t.CompletedId, m2.machineDescription as CompletedDesc
from TransactionsTable t
left join MachineTable m1 on m1.machineNumber=t.CreatedId
left join MachineTable m2 on m2.machineNumber=t.CompletedId
```

(or inner join instead of left join if CreatedId/CompletedId will always be set and the row in machineDescription will always be there).